# Memory physical configuration in Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008

I need to purchase some more memory for a Windows 2008 server, and I need to find out 
1) How many memory slots are available
2) What is the size, speed and other features (i.e. ECC) of the existing memory in each slot.

Obviously I could get that by powering down and looking, but I'd rather avoid an extra trip to the datacenter and the downtime.  Is there way in Windows 2008 server to get that information?  Under Server Manager / Device Manager, I see information on the CPU, hard disks, network cards, but nothing about the RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Powershell :

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_PhysicalMemory | select BankLabel,DeviceLocator,Capacity,Manufacturer,PartNumber,SerialNumber,Speed
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a server from a top-tier vendor (Dell, HP, IBM, possibly SuperMicro), the free management utilities will tell you this stuff as well.